# understanding pointers in linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm having a difficult time understanding pointers. I was under the impression that if  'pointer a' points to  'pointer b', and lets say 'pointer b' changes, 'pointer a' will change with it.

However, in the case of a linked list, such as the following

```
struct Node *deleteFirst(struct Node *head)
{
    if(head != NULL)
    {
       // store the old value of head pointer
       struct Node *temp = head;

       // Change head pointer to point to next node
       head = head->next;

       // delete memory allocated for the previous head node
       free(temp);
    }

    return head;
}
```

why doesn't the pointer of temp change when 'head = head->next;' runs?

Thank you!

Comment: It's almost like asking if `int a = 5;` `int b = a;` `a += 1;`, why doesn't b change? you saved a copy of the value `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate above in the comments, `struct Node *temp = head;` saves a copy the pointer value of `head` to `temp`. Following `head = head->next;`, does not change `temp` since it only holds the copy value of `head`.

To demonstrate the principle but with integers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;

    int* a_ptr = &a;
    int* c = a_ptr; /* c holds a copy of the address of a */

    a_ptr = &b; /* Changes to a_ptr does not affect c */
    printf("%p != %p",a_ptr, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Example Output

```
0x7fff5faceb08 != 0x7fff5faceb0c
```

Perhaps the idea you have is that when a pointer `a` points to another pointer `b`, `a` has reference to `b`, and subsequent changes to `b` affect also `a`. However this is not the case as show in the example above. To mimic the effect of a reference you need the address of the original value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 42;

    int* a_ptr = &a;
    int** c = &a_ptr;

    a_ptr = &b; 
    printf("%p == %p",a_ptr, *c);
}
```

Output

```
0x7fff5dae7b08 == 0x7fff5dae7b08
```

Here changes to `a_ptr` does affect `*c`.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it change? Suppose you have this thing.

```
a = 1;
b = a;
b++;
```

Do you expect `a` to change?

In this case both are different pointer variable holding the same address at one point. You are now changing `head` to hold a different address. Why do you think it would change the other variable? **It won't.**

To clear your idea I will show you:-

```
    [ ]<---next---[ ] <---head

struct Node *temp = head;
    [ ]<---next---[ ] <--head
                   ^
                   |-----temp

Now you change head.head = head->next;
    [ ]<---next---[ ]
     ^             ^
     |             |-----temp
     head
```

In case of pointer, we are basically holding an address. And whatever address we are holding we can change it's content.

```
b = 2
int *a =&b;
*a = 3;
// b is now 3.
```

Now let's check another thing.

```
b=2
c=4
int* a = &b;
int** aa = &a;
```

Now whose address we are holding in `aa`?
Ans:  `a`

So can we change it? yes we can.
`(*aa) = &c;`

So now what did it change? It changed the content of `a`.
// *a is now equal to the value 4.

That's all I guess you need to know to understand pointer I guess. (Using this you can understand almost any pointer related code).

<sub>Extra note:
The code you shown is basically removing a node from the linked list.</sub>